# What is the most reliable method to obtain the base address of the EBDA?

Tags: x86, bootloader, bios, osdev

I am currently working on a bootloader for my operating system. In one part of it, I need to know what the highest usable address of conventional memory is, which also is the base of the EBDA from based on what I've seen. My only issue is that I know that the size of EBDA can vary from BIOS to BIOS. So my question is: What is the most reliable method to obtain the base address of the EBDA / highest usable conventional memory address. I know the BDA can have the EBDA base in it, but it isn't the most reliable way to find it from what I've heard.

Comment: There is a 16-bit word in the Bios Data area at 0x0000:0x0413 that contains the number of kilobytes of available RAM. On a system with 1KiB EBDA this number would be reported as 639. Generally using this number is most reliable.

Comment: If you take that value in KiB and multiply by 64 (or shift left by 6 bits) you will get the segment that the EBDA starts at. So 639*64=40896=0x9FC0. There is also a 16-bit word at 0x0000:0x040E that is supposed to be the segment of the EBDA but on some older systems the value returned isn't always reliable.

Comment: I should point out that the available RAM is the amount of usable usable low memory before the EBDA. On a typical system with no EBDA it would report 640 (640KiB).

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! That makes sense.